# Split a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data frame with different addresses.

| Address |
| --- |
| USA, Utah, Richfield, building 315E |
| Russia, Moscow oblast, Moscow, Arbat District, New street, building 78 |

And I have to split column 'Address' into multiple columns so that each row element is in the correct column like that:

| Country | Region/Sate | City | District | Street | Building |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USA | Utah | Richfield | NA | NA | building 315E |
| Russia | Moscow oblast | Moscow | Arbat District | New street | building 78 |

Could you please help with this?

Comment: What logic can be applied to associate parts of the string with specific columns?

Comment: well, first three elements are always country, sate and city. others can be identified by words like "district", "street" etc.

Comment: @lzvtmtvv Well, then, edit the question to add that criteria. This is part of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative approach that initializes a list with None values

```
import pandas as pd

columns_order = ['Country', 'Region/State', 'City', 'District', 'Street', 'Building']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Address': datas})


def split_address(address):
    parts = address.split(', ')
    num_nones = len(columns_order) - len(parts)
    ordered_parts = parts + [None] * num_nones

    return pd.Series(ordered_parts, index=columns_order)

res = df['Address'].apply(split_address)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

# Minimal reproducible example (that the way you should have given it, fyi :))
df=pd.DataFrame({'Address': ['USA, Utah, Richfield, building 315E', 'Russia, Moscow oblast, Moscow, Arbat District, New street, building 78']})

# Easy part, get country, region, city
splitAddress = df['Address'].str.split(',')
df[['Country', 'Region', 'City']] = splitAddress.str[:3].tolist()
rest = splitAddress.str[3:]

# District, if there is one, should be in first item of unused elements
m=(rest.str.len()>0) & (rest.str[0].str.contains('District'))
df.loc[m, 'District'] = rest[m].str[0]
rest[m]=rest[m].str[1:]

# Street, if there is one, should be the first remaining
m=(rest.str.len()>0) & (rest.str[0].str.contains('street'))
df.loc[m, 'Street'] = rest[m].str[0]
rest[m]=rest[m].str[1:]

# What remains is the rest of address
# WE could just assume that there is only one field left (at most) as in your example. But just in case, rejoin rest
m=rest.str.len()>0
df.loc[m, 'Building'] = rest[m].str.join(', ')
```

I assume that some tuning is required. My detection of what is a district (part containing word "District", case sensitive, and nothing else), a street (part containing word "street", case sensitive, and nothing else) and a building (whatever is not a district nor a street) needs probably some finer test. But from the very few indication you gave... Plus from there you should be able to add criterias.

Also, generally speaking, the `expand=True` parameter of `split` (that was used in a brief answer that has now disappeared) is probably a better way to split a string into columns. I didn't use it, because I don't know how to keep only 3, and then, how to do my "filtering first element of rest, removing what I use" part with it. But maybe there is a way (I am not a "panda guru", so there are many one line code that I code in several lines). But, well, the point is, I don't have any `for` nor any `apply` nor anything that makes part of the iteration pure python. So, even if there might be some faster solutions (may be even twice, or 3 times faster), they should be in the same order of magnitude of speed (nothing like the ×1000 factor we experience when a `for` or some `apply`/`map` are removed)

Answer (score 0):

You can probably try a regex:

```
import re

pat = (r'(?P<Country>[^,]+),\s*'
       r'(?P<State>[^,]+),\s*'
       r'(?P<City>[^,]+)'
       r'(?:,\s*(?P<District>.*district[^,]*))?'
       r'(?:,\s*(?P<Street>.*street[^,]*))?'
       r'(?:,\s*(?P<Building>.*building.*))?')
ADDRESS = re.compile(pat, re.IGNORECASE)
out = df['Address'].str.extract(ADDRESS)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
  Country          State       City        District      Street       Building
0     USA           Utah  Richfield             NaN         NaN  building 315E
1  Russia  Moscow oblast     Moscow  Arbat District  New street    building 78
```

Demo on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yso4o1/1)